# Listening for List updates using the SharePoint Client Object Model

Tags: wpf, sharepoint, object, model, client

I am looking for a decently efficient way to listen for `List` changes on a SharePoint site using only the Client Object Model. I understand how backwards this idea is, but I am trying to keep from having to push any libraries to the SharePoint servers on install.  Everything is supposed to be drop and go on a local machine.

I've thought about a class that just loops a timer and keeps querying the `ClientContext` from the last date of successful query on, but that seems horribly inefficient.

I know this is a ***client*** object model, but is there any way to get notifications from the server on changes from the client only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that this is not possible by using the client object model. If you need to poll too often that the user experience suffers from the slow performance too much, you would need to catch the list changes on the server side. deploy a solution with a feature registering an [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) to your list.

I understand your reluctance to push server-side code to the SP farm; without it, you can save discussions and explanations to the customer's administrators. However, some tasks are more efficient or even feasible only when run on the server. You can consider [Sandbox Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx) for such functionality. They are deployed to SP *not by the farm administrator* but *to a site collection by an site collection administrator* by a friendly web UI. This needs less privileges, more relaxed company policies to comply with, and can be better accepted by your customers. You can develop, test and even use your solution in your site collection only without affecting the entire farm. Microsoft recommends even farm-wide solutions to be designed with as much as possible functionality in sandboxed solutions, putting only the necessary minimum to a farm solution.

If deploying the entire application as sandbox solution would not be possible, you could combine a sandboxed solution gathering the changes with an external web site requesting the gathered data from the site collection, or in you case with a client-only application as you are speaking about. (Sandboxed solutions have one big limitation: You cannot make a web request *from within* the site collection outside; you can only access the site collection *from outside*.)

--- Ferda